# How to apply a function to every two columns of a pandas data and return a new dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For example I have a dataframe as follows:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.049380 | 0.512696 | 0.135421 | 1.396424 |
| 1 | -0.367589 | -0.741008 | -1.543296 | 0.355291 |
| 2 | 1.244623 | -0.295761 | 1.238826 | -0.017174 |
| 3 | 0.378124 | 0.870361 | -0.733288 | -0.228948 |

I want to call `stats.ttest_ind` on all combination of two columns and get new dataframe as follows (don't care the dummy values):

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | nan | 0.512696 | 0.135421 | 1.396424 |
| B | -0.367589 | nan | -1.543296 | 0.355291 |
| C | 1.244623 | -0.295761 | nan | -0.017174 |
| D | 0.378124 | 0.870361 | -0.733288 | nan |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
ttest_lists = [[ stats.ttest_ind(df[col_i], df[col_j]) if col_i!=col_j else np.nan 
                for col_i in df] for col_j in df]
```

To get a `DataFrame` rather than a list of lists, you can then use:

```
ttest_df = pd.DataFrame(ttest_lists, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
```

Comment: Also, if you're doing statistical testing multiple times, *be careful* to account for p-hacking. If you are testing with a significance level of 5%, then with 6 different pairs of A,B,C,D then the chance that you falsely reject the null hypothesis would increase beyond 5%, potentially significantly.

If you have more than 4 columns, say n, 6 different pairs becomes 0.5*n*(n-1) different pairs, and the problem becomes even more important to address.